# Adding subsequent months on x-axis using Live Charts

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

```
 private int SumOfNodes()
    {
        ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
        Test t = new Test(MDM);

        List<Hardware> SumOfHardware = t.GetHardware().FindAll(x => x.Nodes != 0);

        int SumOfNodes = 0;

        foreach (Hardware i in SumOfHardware )
        {
            SumOfNodes += i.Nodes;
        }

        return SumOfNodes;
    }


    private int SumOfRepeaters()
    {
        ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
        Test t = new Test(MDM);

        List<Hardware> SumOfHardware = t.GetHardware().FindAll(x => x.Repeaters != 0);

        int SumOfRepeaters = 0;

        foreach (Hardware i in SumOfHardware)
        {
            SumOfRepeaters += i.Repeaters;
        }

        return SumOfRepeaters;
    }

    private int SumOfHubs()
    {
        ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
        Test t = new Test(MDM);

        List<Hardware> SumOfHardware = t.GetHardware().FindAll(x => x.Hubs != 0);

        int SumOfHubs= 0;

        foreach (Hardware i in SumOfHardware)
        {
            SumOfHubs += i.Hubs;
        }

        return SumOfHubs;
    }

    private string Month()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");

        return month;
    }

    private void DisplayData()
    {

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
                {
                      Title = "Nodes",
                      Values = new ChartValues<int> { SumOfNodes() }
                },


        };

        SeriesCollection.Add
        (
            new ColumnSeries
            {
                Title = "Repeaters",
                Values = new ChartValues<int> { SumOfRepeaters() }
            }
        );

        SeriesCollection.Add
       (
           new ColumnSeries
           { 
               Title = "Hubs",
               Values = new ChartValues<int> { SumOfHubs() }
           }
       );



        Labels = new[] { Month() };
        Formatter = value => value.ToString("N");

        DataContext = this;

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPPYA.png)

At this points I've managed to create an app that adds/removes and updates my items on my database. I'm also planning to add some stats (Started off with graph visualisation) but I'm facing an issue.
I want to seperate columns  based on months. So for example as seen by the image attached no matter how many items i add , remove or update the total amount for each item is added to Decemeber. But when January comes any newly added modification to the quantity of my items I would like to see adjacent to the Decemeber one. 
P.S.: There is alot of code repitition which will accounted for later on.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to put something together regarding my answer above which may be usefull for someone in the future
What I've done was to
1) Get my data from my db.
2) Find the Month of interest using LINQ queries **

- instead of selecting the items (i.e repeaters, nodes)

**
3) By doing so it also accounts for the items I'm interested in during the month of interest.
4) Do an incremental foreach loop as shown in my code above.
5) Change the methodd i want to display (i.e DisplayData to DisplayDecemberData) and use in the same way as above.
6) Create further methods for the subsequent months and just add the additional information in the ChartValues object.

See Below

```
private int DecemberNodes()
    {
        ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
        Test t = new Test(MDM);

        List<Hardware> decembernodes = t.GetHardware().FindAll(x => x.Date.Month==12);

        int DecemberSumOfNodes = 0;

        foreach (Hardware i in decembernodes)
        {
            DecemberSumOfNodes += i.Nodes;
        }

        return DecemberSumOfNodes;
    }


    private int JanuaryNodes()
    {
        ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
        Test t = new Test(MDM);

        List<Hardware> januarynodes = t.GetHardware().FindAll(x => x.Date.Month==01);

        int JanuarySumOfNodes = 0;

        foreach (Hardware i in januarynodes)
        {
            JanuarySumOfNodes += i.Nodes;
        }


     private void DisplayDecemberData()
    {

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
                {
                      Title = "Nodes",
                      Values = new ChartValues<int> { DecemberNodes()  }
                },


        };


     private void DisplayJanuaryData()
    {

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
                {
                      Title = "Nodes",
                      **Values = new ChartValues<int> { DecemberNodes(),  JanuaryNodes()  }**
                },


        };
```

There is some code repetition and I'm pretty sure there is a more code concise  way of actually doing it but for now this seems to do the trick. When I simplify the code i will post it.